# How can I implement Tilda functionality in byobu?

Tags: gnome-terminal, byobu, tilda

What I really like about tilda is the key binding allowing me to pop it on top of whatever i'm working on and then after I finish with my terminal commands make it run in the background. Is it possible to achieve this functionality in byobu?

Answer (score 0):

set byobu as custom command in tilda prefs . then just use tilda .

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this answer with an explanation of how to do that.